# Why i can't re-scale the keyframes from a keyed geometry animation on the dope-sheet?

Tags: animation, keyframes, dopesheet

I'm having the problem that i can't re-scale (move) the Keyframes made by keyed animations of my geometry...when i do that the animation just appears as the same as before, but i did move the keyframes, but nothing happens at all.

[image]

Comment: Did you cache the animation maybe?

Comment: It should work. it looks like you have selected "paso2" object but "paso1" keyframe in dopesheet.